# How can i retrieve data from method of wmi class?

Tags: hyper-v

Good day, I am currently trying to do this:

```
out = connection.query("Select * From 
     Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService.Msvm_SummaryInformation")
```

However, I need to find Ram usage by virtual machine of `hyper-v` host. Any idea how to obtain this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about `get-vm | select name, *mem*` for a script on vm ram use this: https://powershell.org/2012/11/01/powershell-hyper-v-memory-report/

Comment: I need it in python, not in Powershell.

Comment: have you tried querying `Msvm_MemorySettingData`?

Comment: Thank u so much, I got total allocated RAM from Msvm_MemorySettingData, You have any idea about to calculate Used RAM by virtual machine????

Answer (score 0):

to query the memory settings use `Msvm_MemorySettingData`. To get the currently allocated/used RAM query `Msvm_Memory` (property `NumberOfBlocks`).

For more information about WMI classes please use the information provided here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136986(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank u. May I know how can I find read block size and write block size for both host and VM level?  Blocks occupied by the block size                                                        For ex: read_block_size(512 bytes - 1024 bytes)